# Oz dictionary with composite typed keys

Tags: dictionary, oz, mozart

The CTM book says, "A dictionary is a mapping from simple constants (atoms, names, or integers) to partial values."

As expected, when we execute this code:

```
declare
Memo = {NewDictionary}
try {Dictionary.put Memo 3        1} catch E then skip end
try {Dictionary.put Memo 5.5      2} catch E then skip end
try {Dictionary.put Memo foo      3} catch E then skip end
try {Dictionary.put Memo foo(bar) 4} catch E then skip end
try {Dictionary.put Memo baz#qux  5} catch E then skip end
{Browse {Dictionary.entries Memo}}
```

we get `[3#1 foo#3]`.

Are there any common workarounds for using the other types as keys? At the moment, I need to store some data in a sparse matrix, for which, a dictionary ought to have been good enough. But it would be nice to have a general-purpose workaround.